# How can I delay a :hover effect in CSS?

Tags: css, hover, delay

Is there a way to delay the :Hover event without using JavaScript? I know there is a way to delay animations, but I haven't seen anything on delaying the :hover event.

I'm building a son-of-suckerfish like menu. I'd like to simulate what hoverIntent does without adding the extra JS weight. I'd prefer to treat this as a progressive enhancement and not make JS a requirement for using the menu.

Example of menu markup:

```
<div>
    <div>
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#">
                <ul>
                    <li></li>
                    <li></li>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li>
            <li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

Here is the full demo: http://jsfiddle.net/aEgV3/

Comment: Interesting question, but I think 'no; not without JavaScript' is likely to be the answer, unfortunately.

Answer (score 210, accepted):

You can use transitions to delay the `:hover` effect you want, if the effect is CSS-based.

For example

```
div{
    transition: 0s background-color;
}

div:hover{
    background-color:red;    
    transition-delay:1s;
}
```

this will delay applying the the hover effects (*`background-color` in this case*) for one second.

---

Demo of delay on both hover on and off:

```css
div{
    display:inline-block;
    padding:5px;
    margin:10px;
    border:1px solid #ccc;
    transition: 0s background-color;
    transition-delay:1s;
}
div:hover{
    background-color:red;
}
```

```html
<div>delayed hover</div>
```

Demo of delay only on hover on:

```css
div{
    display:inline-block;
    padding:5px;
    margin:10px;
    border:1px solid #ccc;
    transition: 0s background-color;
}
div:hover{
    background-color:red;    
    transition-delay:1s;
}
```

```html
<div>delayed hover</div>
```

---

[Vendor Specific Extentions for Transitions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/CSS/CSS_transitions#AutoCompatibilityTable) and [W3C CSS3 transitions](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-transitions/#contents)

Comment: I updated my question... I'm not sure if a transition would work in my case or not. I have sub menus positioned of screen and being put back in place on hover.

Comment: But how to set time for in and out. Like when user keep mouse on div for 1sec... then transition occurs. But when move out.. then immediately transition goes out..

Comment: The property to handle the transition duration is a different one. You can manipulate them distinctly to achieve the effect you want, example: http://dabblet.com/gist/332903040f1f07754d1f

Comment: @VictoriaStuart depends on how you show/hide it. If it is with `display` property no, but if you move it off screen then yes.

Comment: The duration will take effect on :active too. You need to reset the delay to 0s on :active in order to avoid waiting before any :active transition takes effect.

Comment: I am trying to delay the rotate transform on hover effect slow a bit. But its not slow. Whats wrong I am doing here ? Below is the css code 

.eael-offcanvas-toggle{
    transition: rotate 500ms;
}

.eael-offcanvas-toggle::after{content: "///"; color: #322625; font-size: 30px;}

.eael-offcanvas-toggle:hover::after{color: #c1252b; transition: 0.1s ease-in !important; content: "|||"; transform: rotate(-0deg);}

.eael-offcanvas-toggle::before{}

Comment: @Md.AmanurRahman you cannot rotate the change of content. You can use the same three lines though and [`skew`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/transform-function/skew) them. Something like https://jsfiddle.net/gaby/1vrxfmhz/5/

Answer (score 16):

```
div {
     background: #dbdbdb;
    -webkit-transition: .5s all;   
    -webkit-transition-delay: 5s; 
    -moz-transition: .5s all;   
    -moz-transition-delay: 5s; 
    -ms-transition: .5s all;   
    -ms-transition-delay: 5s; 
    -o-transition: .5s all;   
    -o-transition-delay: 5s; 
    transition: .5s all;   
    transition-delay: 5s; 
}

div:hover {
    background:#5AC900;
    -webkit-transition-delay: 0s;
    -moz-transition-delay: 0s;
    -ms-transition-delay: 0s;
    -o-transition-delay: 0s;
    transition-delay: 0s;
}
```

This will add a transition delay, which will be applicable to almost every browser..

Answer (score -8):

For a more aesthetic appearance :) can be:

```
left:-9999em; 
top:-9999em;
```

position for `.sNv2 .nav UL` can be replaced by `z-index:-1` and `z-index:1` for `.sNv2 .nav LI:Hover UL`