# How would I add a 1 second delay to the hide JavaScript function

Tags: javascript, jquery, function, hide, delay

This is some JavaScript I have for a simple navigation bar but I have issues with the drop down disappearing before you can click on them so I want to add a delay after the mouse leaves the bar before they hide.

How would I do that?

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        // Navigation bar drop-down
        $("nav ul li").hover(function () {
            $(this).addClass("active");
            $(this).find("ul").show().animate({ opacity: 1 }, 400);
        }, function () {
            // Delay on hiding should go here
            $(this).find("ul").hide().animate({ opacity: 0 }, 200);
            $(this).removeClass("active");
        });
        $('nav ul li ul li:first-child').prepend('<li class="arrow"></li>');
        $('nav ul li:first-child').addClass('first');
        $('nav ul li:last-child').addClass('last');
        $('nav ul li ul').parent().append('<span class="dropdown"></span>').addClass('drop');
    });
</script>
```

Thanks in advance to anyone who can help

P.S. This is probably really obvious but I know very little about JavaScript. :L

Comment: Java != Javascript  Two completely different languages; two very different purposes, environments and uses

Comment: jQuery http://api.jquery.com/delay/

Comment: Javascript is awesome and powerful, glad you're learning it!  Good luck!

Answer (score 3):

> I have a simple navigation bar

Don't use JavaScript then. This can and should be done with CSS. CSS transitions and selectors allow to define exactly what you want.

See also [Delay :Hover in CSS3?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8566090/1048572) and the [excellent example](http://jsfiddle.net/aEgV3/) from there.

Comment: OK, links added. I didn't want to repeat it :)

Answer (score 2):

Don't use a huge function such as `delay()`. Just use `setTimeout()`.

```
var that = this
setTimeout(function() {
    $(that).hide() // Do your stuff, just don't forget that "this" has changed
}, 1000) // Define your delay in milliseconds here
```

The function inside the `setTimeout` will execute after the delay specified as a second argument.

Comment: delay() is not really a huge function. It pops your anonymous function onto a queue stack, calls it through setTimeout(), and returns a jQuery object. You're not looking at any sort of performance hit, since obviously you're not going to be running delay in a loop anyway.

Answer (score 2):

You can do it like this.  You use the `delay()` method to set up the delay and you use `.stop(true)` on both hover functions in case the user goes out and comes back in during the delay.  The `.stop(true)` will clear any queued animations.  I also switched the code to `fadeIn()` and `fadeOut()` because those automatically do the `show()` and `hide()` as needed.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        // Navigation bar drop-down
        $("nav ul li").hover(function () {
            $(this).addClass("active");
            $(this).find("ul").stop(true).fadeIn(400);
        }, function () {
            // Delay on hiding should go here
            var self = $(this);
            self.find("ul").stop(true).delay(1500).fadeOut(400, function() {
                self.removeClass("active");
            });
        });
        $('nav ul li ul li:first-child').prepend('<li class="arrow"></li>');
        $('nav ul li:first-child').addClass('first');
        $('nav ul li:last-child').addClass('last');
        $('nav ul li ul').parent().append('<span class="dropdown"></span>').addClass('drop');
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you can do something like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        // Navigation bar drop-down
        $("nav ul li").hover(function () {
            $(this).addClass("active");
            $(this).find("ul").show().animate({ opacity: 1 }, 400);
        }, function () {
            // Delay on hiding should go here
            $(this).find("ul").hide().delay(1000).animate({ opacity: 0 }, 200, function() {
                $(this).removeClass("active");
            });  
        });
        $('nav ul li ul li:first-child').prepend('<li class="arrow"></li>');
        $('nav ul li:first-child').addClass('first');
        $('nav ul li:last-child').addClass('last');
        $('nav ul li ul').parent().append('<span class="dropdown"></span>').addClass('drop');
    });
</script>
```

Comment: The `.removeClass()` won't properly here because `this` will be the nested `ul`, not the `li` that it was in the OP's code.  In addition, I think you have to properly handle the case where the mouse goes out and then comes back in during the delay.

Answer (score 1):

You could use delay().

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        // Navigation bar drop-down
        $("nav ul li").hover(function () {
            $(this).addClass("active");
            $(this).find("ul").show().animate({ opacity: 1 }, 400);
        }, function () {
            // Delay on hiding should go here
        $(this).find("ul").delay(5000).fadeOut();
            $(this).removeClass("active");
        });
        $('nav ul li ul li:first-child').prepend('<li class="arrow"></li>');
        $('nav ul li:first-child').addClass('first');
        $('nav ul li:last-child').addClass('last');
        $('nav ul li ul').parent().append('<span class="dropdown"></span>').addClass('drop');
    });

</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

Very interesting. Nothing hides, until you mouseout.
[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/FCert/2/)