# jQuery menu hover delay without hoverintent plugin

Tags: jquery, menu

Hi am trying to add hover delay on menu, and I can't use hoverIntent plugin

```
 $('#topMenu #menu>li').hover(function () {
     $(this).children('#subNav3').show();
     $(this).addClass('linkExtend');

},

function () {
     $(this).children('#subNav3').hide();
    $(this).removeClass('linkExtend');
});
```

Please find [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/3f8mC/2/)

So as per demo if I try to move mouse from menu 2 to menu 2.1

Comment: You've already tried `.delay()`?

Comment: Isn't this easier done with a pure CSS menu? Since it is quite critical to the experience, a menu should always work. Relying on Js would be liability in that. Css 3 supports delay I think.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8566090/delay-hover-in-css3

Comment: @Digitalis, comments is not the place for this.  The OP has a specific question about jQuery and not CSS3.

Comment: True that, hence the comment. It's not an answer, its a suggestion.