# Delay in CSS transitions

Tags: html, css, css-transitions

I have 2 images on top of each other, positioned absolute, in my example they are square but in my real project they are pngs with some transparency in the borders so the one in the back needs to be hidden until it appears on hover.

My problem is I need the transition to have some kind of delay so that the back pic appears a bit before the one on top so you don't see the background in between. I have made a fiddle to illustrate this:
http://jsfiddle.net/L21sk0oh/

You can clearly see the red from the background, that shouldn't happen. Also there is some weird moving going on, I haven't noticed this in my actual project.

Also my HTML:

```
<div class="product1">
    <img class="active" src="http://lorempixel.com/400/200/sports" alt="">
    <img class="inactive" src="http://lorempixel.com/400/200/" alt="">
</div>
```

And my css:

```
body{
    background: red;
}
.product1{
  position: relative;
    width: 400px;
    height: 200px;
}

img{
  position: absolute;
  top:0;
  left:0;
}

.product1 img.active{
  transition: all 1s ease-in-out;
  opacity: 1;
}

.product1 img.inactive{
  transition: all 1s ease-in-out;
  opacity: 0;
}

.product1:hover img.active{
  opacity: 0;
}

.product1:hover img.inactive{
  opacity: 1;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could specify a value for the [`transition-delay` property](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/transition).

In this case, I added a `1s` delay to the transition shorthand of `.product1 img.active`:

[**Updated Example**](http://jsfiddle.net/Lg0umzL6/)

```
.product1 img.active {
  transition: all 1s 1s ease-in-out;
  opacity: 1;
}
```

The above is equivalent to:

```
.product1 img.active{
  transition: all 1s ease-in-out;
  transition-delay: 1s;
  opacity: 1;
}
```

Make sure you're adding the [transition shorthand properties](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/transition) in the correct order.

Comment: Can I have the delay only for the mouseenter?

Comment: Nvermind, this answered my question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8566090/delay-hover-in-css3