# Css hover delay (filter)

Tags: css

i use a greyscale filter for an image on my page and a very saturated filter for hover.

When the image is hovered, i want the img to have a delay of 2-3sec untill it gets saturated.

My codes are:

```
.image2{
    max-width:70%;
    border-radius: 5px;

    filter: grayscale(1);
    -webkit-filter: grayscale(1);
    -moz-filter: grayscale(1);
    -o-filter: grayscale(1);
    -ms-filter: grayscale(1);
}
.image2:hover{
    filter: saturate(500%),2s;
    -webkit-filter: saturate(500%);
    -moz-filter: saturate(500%);
    -o-filter: saturate(500%);
    -ms-filter: saturate(500%);
}
```

I tried playing with the `transition-delay` and several others but none worked.

Thanks for answering :)

Comment: Check this question out: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8566090/delay-hover-in-css3. This will probably solve your problem.

Comment: In order for `transition-delay` to work you need to define the `transition` (and browser specific equivalents) for `filter` (and browser specific equivalents), or, as I did in the answer, use the generic `all`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you need is [transition-delay](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_transition-delay.asp):

```
.image2 {
    -webkit-transition: all .4s ease;
    -moz-transition: all .4s ease;
    -o-transition: all .4s ease;
    transition: all .4s ease;
    -webkit-transition-delay: 3s;
    transition-delay: 3s;
}
```

It's quite simple, really: when a certain CSS property of an element changes, before applying the change browsers will check if there is any `transition` set for that particular CSS property. 
If there is one, the browser will check for `transition-delay`. But if no `transition` is set, there is nothing to delay, so `transition-delay` is useless.

In the above example, the transition itself is set to 0.4 seconds and it will start at 3 seconds after you hover (but beware that you need to hover the element for 3 seconds, otherwise the transition gets canceled).

I added a `transition-delay` of 3 seconds to the *classic* [filter example](https://jsfiddle.net/KDtAX/4003/) to get a feel of how it all behaves.

Comment: thanks a lot for the answer but yet doesn't work. I probably do something wrong but i tried adding and changing the values several times and still nothing. mersi frumos de raspuns oricum :) o sa mai incerc sa vad ce reusesc :D

Comment: Make a codepen or jsfiddle with it and I'll take a look. There's something else that's interfering with it. It should work. As you can see, it does in my example.